# Changing background image with time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change wallpaper every 3 seconds, but only the first one works. I have no idea what to do :(. After the first picture it simply puts there images[x] but not the value in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>
  <head>
    <title>Takumi</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Novy2.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body onload = "startTimer()">
  <script>
  var x;
  x=0;
  function displayNextImage() {
      x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
      document.getElementById("mid").style="background-image : url(images[x])";
  }

  function startTimer() {
      setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
  }

  var images = [], x = -1;
  images[0] = image3.jpg;
  images[1] = image2.jpg;
  images[2] = image1.jpg;
  </script>

  <div id="mid" style="background-image : url(image1.jpg)">

  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: missing quotes around image filename. Should be images[0] = 'image3.jpg';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the array of images, enclose the image filenames in quotes because they are strings:

```
  var images = [], x = -1;
  images[0] = 'image3.jpg';
  images[1] = 'image2.jpg';
  images[2] = 'image1.jpg';
```

Then you have to concatenate the image file name, not just print the word images[x] .. do this:

```
document.getElementById("mid").style="background-image : url("+ images[x] +")";
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer so others can learn from it too.

Answer (score 2):

change your `startTimer()` function to this

```
function startTimer() {
    setInterval(function() {
       displayNextImage();
    }, 3000);
}
```

and your image files need quotes

```
var images = [], x = -1;
images[0] = 'image3.jpg';
images[1] = 'image2.jpg';
images[2] = 'image1.jpg';
```

and you also need to have quotes in the url so it should look like this..

```
document.getElementById("mid").style="background-image : url(' + images[x] + ')";
```

Comment: Thank you. But I cant use quotes in style="background-image : url(image1.jpg)" because there cant be style="background-image : url('image1.jpg')" :(

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the style with plaintext "images[x]".
You will need to stop the string and concatenate your desired image path to it.
`'url('+foo[bar]+')'`

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea how to stop the string.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById("mid").style="background-image : url(images[x])";
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("mid").style="background-image : url('" + images[x] + "')";
```

Also, change those lines:

```
images[0] = image3.jpg;
images[1] = image2.jpg;
images[2] = image1.jpg;
```

To:

```
images[0] = "image3.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";
images[2] = "image1.jpg";
```

First change is, that, images[x] is not evaluated (since you are providing it as part of string). Now, you concat string and actual value of array "images", on index "x".

Second change is, you simply need quotes, to actually provide string values. Otherwise, you have syntax errors, that "image1" is undefined. Or something like "Cannot get property 'jpg' on undefined". JS tries to evaluate those lines, and those are meant to be literals.